# Backreferencing in R (Regular Expressions)

Tags: regex, r

I'm not sure why I can't get a simple back reference to work in R/RStudio.

`grepl('name\1','namename')` returns FALSE.  `grepl('(name)\1','namename')` is no good either.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the double backlash before `1` (the regex engine will understand it as a single backslash):

```
grepl('(name)\\1', 'namename')
## [1] TRUE
```

This is because:

```
cat('(name)\\1')
## (name)\1
```

In your case, `\1 == \001` means an ASCII character of code 1.

```
charToRaw('\1')
## [1] 01
```

Comment: I spent an embarrassing amount of time struggling with this before turning to stackoverflow.  You guys never let me down!